# phpunit - wrong path

Tags: php, zend-framework, path, terminal, phpunit

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?
I've installed phpunit, and everything is fine when I'm in the /opt/local/PEAR directory, so if I go to /opt/local/PEAR directory and run phpunit I get:

> PHPUnit 3.5.11 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>   Usage: phpunit [switches] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
>          phpunit [switches] 
>   blablabla

but if I am on some other path I get:

> Warning: require_once(PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 38
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 38

I know that is something wrong with my PATH. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Try adding `/opt/local/PEAR` to your `php.ini` file include_path.

```
//Before:
include_path='.:/usr/lib/php'
//After:
include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/opt/local/PEAR'
```

You may also need to restart your web server afterwards for the changes to take effect.

And as RobertPitt comments, this can also be done at runtime without access to the php.ini file.

```
<?php
$path = '/opt/local/PEAR';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
?>
```

Comment: you can also do this at runtime as well, I think you should add this on to your answer.

Comment: +1, sidenode: Since phpunit is executed from the command line there should be no need to restart a webserver (if he has one running)

Answer (score 7):

The PEAR channel (pear.phpunit.de) that is used to distribute PHPUnit needs to be registered with the local PEAR environment. Furthermore, component that PHPUnit depends upon are hosted on additional PEAR channels.

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

This has to be done only once. Now the PEAR Installer can be used to install packages from the PHPUnit channel:

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had to uninstall it first, added the discover channels and then installed it again.

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu, I used

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu edit this php.ini for CLI:

```
 /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

add /usr/local/lib/php/ to your include line

```
include_path= "/opt/zend/library/:/var/www/library/:/usr/local/bin/pear/:/usr/local/lib/php/"
```

Took me a day to figure it out. Bingo.

If this does not work, try this, it will give you a hint where your PHP libs are located.

```
$ locate PHP_CodeCoverage
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know PEAR installation method comes to his end, this is what's says about it on the github repository.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method